# How to get CSS around links like login button

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

Here is the site http://www.2playermode.com/

You notice the login button. it has the nice black background done by css. How can i replicate that. I have php statements with them or some are just play links..

I have a register , lost password , and logout and admin that i need done same way. This is wordpress platform if that helps any.

Here are the code for some of them Once you login you will see them but here is code that should help.

here is some of the code

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Lost your password?</a>
```

here is more complicated

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('index.php'); ?>">Log out</a>    |                <?php if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {                     echo '<a href="' . admin_url() . '">' . __('Admin') . '</a>'; } else {                  echo '<a href="' . admin_url() . 'profile.php">' . __('Profile') . '</a>'; } ?>
```

I have been trying different options to get the same result but come up failing. As you see the admin url and profile url i need to have same images but that is only shown once logged in.

Comment: I did use firebug. When i tried to put it in a div with textarea, or submit ID nothing in the background would show up ? I also wrote custom css using firebug and still unable to get it. I am sure i am just writing the div wrong or the css to link wrong.  I am sure it is something very simple

Comment: Also when i try to style the <? php    /> everything goes stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the CSS on the page (copied and pasted):

```
input[type="submit"] {
   cursor: pointer;
}
input, textarea, select, fieldset {
   color: #D1D1D1;
   border: 2px solid #202020;
   background: #111;
}
input, textarea {
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 9pt;
   padding: 5px;
}
* {
   outline: none;
}
```

So just add the a-tag to the CSS

Comment: curious i tried to add just this   
     #userinfo a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #111111;
    border: 2px solid #202020;
    color: #D1D1D1;
}     but it did not work

Comment: i finally put the correct code                                                                                                                                                        .userinfo p a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #111111;
    border: 2px solid #202020;
    color: #D1D1D1;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 9pt;
    padding: 5px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Get: http://getfirebug.com/ for FF, or use the console of Chrome (ctrl+shift+j) and inspect the html element for it's css-rules.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-off, custom css is probably the way to go.

But if you're doing a lot of these things, by far the easiest way to style buttons, links, and input=submit elements is [jQuery's UI button](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/)  It's cross-browser tested, validates, and is well-thought out for accessibility.  The biggest bonus is that setting it up is just a matter of adding 2-3 classes to any element.

The other thing that makes jQuery UI so great is [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).  With it, you simple define a style on a simple GUI, upload a file, and voila....styled website elements.  I actually use themeroller for most of the elements of my applications, which I can then restyle based on a client's logo colors or preferences with a simple upload.  On one app, we even allow the user to switch the theme on the fly via this method.  In my mind, you can't beat it.

Comment: this does look interesting but i have to have the same look as what is there now.